# Access service by publicIP using istio-ingress gives 503 Servcie unavailable error

Tags: istio, azure-aks

My service is working fine when I use port-forwarding and send a get request to the localhost however sending a Get request to the publicDomain gives 503 error message.
Here is my configuration files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
   name: my-app
   namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
   - port: 8080
     targetPort: 8080
     protocol: TCP
     name: http
   - port: 9000
     targetPort: 9000
     protocol: TCP
     name: http1
   - port: 9001
     targetPort: 9001
     protocol: TCP
     name: http2
   selector:
     app: my-app
```

The Deployment config:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
       app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: myrepo.azurecr.io/my-app:12
          name: my-app
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 8000
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9000
              protocol: TCP
            - containerPort: 9001
              protocol: TCP
```

The VirtualService config:

```
 apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
 kind: VirtualService
 metadata:
   name: my-app
   namespace: default
 spec:
   hosts:
     - "app.mydomain.com"
   gateways:
     - mygateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
   http:
     - match:
       - uri:
         prefix: /myprefix
       route:
        - destination:
           host: my-app
           port:
             number: 9001
     - match:
       - uri:
         prefix: /
       route:
        - destination:
          host: my-app
          port:
            number: 9000
     corsPolicy:
       allowOrigin:
       - "https://test1.domain.com"
       - "https://test2.domain.com"
       allowMethods:
       - POST
       - PATCH
       allowCredentials: false
       allowHeaders:
       - X-Tenant-Identifier
       - Content-Type
       maxAge: "24h"
```

Gateway config:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
      - "*.mydomain.com"
    #tls:
    #httpsRedirect: true
    - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
      - "*.mydomain.com"
    tls:
     mode: SIMPLE
     serverCertificate: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.crt
     privateKey: /etc/istio/ingressgateway-certs/tls.key
```

Here is some more info:

```
$ kubectl get ep my-app
NAME              ENDPOINTS                                               AGE
my-app   10.244.1.169:9000,10.244.1.169:9001,10.244.1.169:8080   26h
```

If I forward the port:

```
 $ kubectl port-forward my-app-podid 6001:9001
```

and then use postman to send a Get request to localhost:6001/myprefix it's working fine and return 200 OK response, however if send a Get request to publicdomain app.mydomain.com/myprefix I get 503 error also using curl:

```
kubectl exec -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway-podid -- curl -v http://my-app.default.svc.cluster.local:9001/myprefix
```

Connected to my-app.default.svc.cluster.local (10.0.71.212) port 9001 (#0)

> GET /myprefix HTTP/1.1
>   Host: my-app.default.svc.cluster.local:9001
>   User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
>   Accept: */*
>
> upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable

The logs of ingress gateway doesn't give more info than just 503 error message.
Does anyone know what is missing?

Comment: 1. Can you confirm if sidecar injections to your deployment pods were successful? 2. If You use mTLS policy did You make destination rule for HTTP (non mTLS) traffic? If you have troubles finding out those things, write a comment and I will prepare commands and steps to verify that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was setting up wrong port names under Service.
So the correct Service.yaml file looks like bellow:

```
 apiVersion: v1
 kind: Service
 metadata:
   name: my-app
   namespace: default
 spec:
   ports:
    - port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    name: http-debug
    - port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
    protocol: TCP
    name: http-app
    - port: 9001
    targetPort: 9001
    protocol: TCP
    name: http-monitoring
  selector:
   app: my-app
```

https://istio.io/docs/setup/additional-setup/requirements/

Comment: I can't see any requirements related to your issue in the linked website. I also cannot see from your posts how you actually fixed the issue. Did you change the ports? The names? If the latter, I can't see the names again anywhere in your configs.